# How to update specific tab icon in tabhost android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I've 4 tabs, one of them is notification icon. By default set all icons using tab specifications.

```
spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Four");
                        spec.setContent(R.id.tab5);
                        spec.setContent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ICNotificationActivity.class));
                            spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_notification_noted));
host.addTab(spec);
```

After a delay i have to update tab 4 icon with another resource file . How to update tabhost? Is there any update funtion available like **host.addTab(spec)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am looping all tabs and change the color and icon of selected tab.
in for the loop i am setting all tab to unselected first than only selected tab is set to updated icons and color.

```
private void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost, int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        //      unselected
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_unselected);

        TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_white));
    }
    if (position > 0) {
        //      selected
        tabhost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(position);
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab())
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selected);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_color));
    }

}
```

> you can call above method by using

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do something here
     setTabColor(myTabHost, myTabPosition);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference .  Shows this log error.   {  host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();
        host.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
        host.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.border_tab_activity);
        host.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());} , already defined tabhost.

Comment: @SARATHV i have given my code you need to change as per your need.

Comment: code works fine, thanks . i have made mistake at tabposition, thats why i got nullpointer exception